# Calling a scope function in a UI-grid link

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I'm working with making tables using UI-Grid. I want to call a scope function when a cell's content is clicked. In this case when a cell is clicked an alert should appear. Here's my javascript file.

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngTouch', 'ui.grid', 'ui.grid.exporter', 'ui.grid.selection']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$interval', '$q', function ($scope, $http, $interval, $q) {
    $scope.gridOptions = {};

    $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs = [{name: 'ID', field: 'id', cellTemplate: '<a ng-href="#" ng-click="test()">{{row.entity.id}}</a>'}];

    $scope.test = function() {
        window.alert("Alert");
    }

}]);
```

And my web page:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="app" class="ng-scope">
  <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.16/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.16/angular-touch.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.16/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ui-grid.info/docs/grunt-scripts/csv.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ui-grid.info/docs/grunt-scripts/pdfmake.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ui-grid.info/docs/grunt-scripts/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ui-grid.info/release/ui-grid.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ui-grid.info/release/ui-grid.css" type="text/css">

    <style type="text/css">
    .grid {
        width: auto;
        height: 500px;
        margin-left: 50px;
        margin-right: 50px;
        margin-top: 50px;
        margin-bottom: 50px;
    }
    </style>

  </head>
  <body>

<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div id="grid0" ui-grid="gridOptions" ui-grid-exporter ui-grid-selection class="grid"></div>

</div>

  </body>
</html>
```

This does not work and I cannot figure out why.

Comment: You have a few problems. `$scope.gridOptions` has not been initialized. `cellTamplate` is spelt wrong. And you're not giving the grid any data by doing `ui-grid="metaGridOptions"`.

Comment: All of those were caused by sloppily copying my code. I fixed them here but none of them appear in my source code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To call the $scope level function from a template you will have to use grid.appScope. In you case it will be `grid.appScope.test()`

```
cellTemplate: '<a ng-href="#" ng-click="grid.appScope.test()">{{row.entity.Locked}}</a>'
```

Sample here http://plnkr.co/edit/KyxhAXQVYPfnZPcNh9Ce?p=preview